# Angular and Bootstrap Button group

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

We're using Angular together with Bootstrap. We created a button group like

```
<div class="input-group-append">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
      [(ngModel)]="currentDisplayedList"
      (ngModelChange)="changeFilter()"
      btnRadio="subscribed" >subscribed</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
      [(ngModel)]="currentDisplayedList"
      (ngModelChange)="changeFilter()"
      btnRadio="available">available</button>
    <button *ngIf="getPerm()?.canDeleteRss()"
      class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
      [(ngModel)]="currentDisplayedList"
      (ngModelChange)="changeFilter()"
      btnRadio="deleted">deleted</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

After some different upgrades in Angular the major problem is the init of the component. At the init the `ngModelChange`is fired three times in a row - for each button separately. Which triggers the function `changeFilter()` and performs all the actions (retrieving data from DB) multiple times.

Is there a 'simple' way to prevent this and call it only once?

Comment: Just throwing out an idea. One way is to moved the `changeFilter()` code into a subject and put a debounceTime 500ms on it.

Comment: Yeah... might be an idea.... But how would you do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

First create a `Subject`, add a debounceTime of 500ms and subscribe to it.

```
var onChangeFilter$ = new Subject();

var subscription = onChangeFilter$.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(_=>{
   this.onChangeFilter();
});
```

Then rewrite the `ngModelChange` to simply call `next()` on the subject.

```
(ngModelChange)="triggerChangeFilter()"

triggerChangeFilter(){
    this.onChangeFilter$.next();
}
```

Make sure to destroy the subscription on `ngDestroy`

```
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. The main problem with this approach is that the `debounceTime` causes a change in the init sequence and than I cannot any longer distinguish between user interaction and init-procedure :-/ So, your approach works but not for the init-phase!

Comment: Do you have `currentDisplayList` as `@input`, and an api call in `changeFilter()` which also sets the `currentDisplayList`? Could you create a stackblitz sample?